# socketstream and 3rd party repos

Tags: javascript, node.js, socketstream

How can I add a bunch js files but include only one of them for client code? E.g. I need to use [hammer.js](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.) and want add it as submodule. I can not simply add it in client/code/app cuz `SS` will try to load all contents of repo (including README.md).

Comment: Well. I can answer my own question. The guys at AOL for some reason decided to wrap any library in the modules, which are located in the `client/code` (exception is `client/code/libs`). This information was already known from the documentation. But I was hoping that there is a way to put third-party library in the `client/code`  and include only one file from it. Look at [source](http://d.pr/GoBZ) and you'll see simply hardcore without any possibility to configure the behavior

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `code` portion of your `ss.client.define` so that Socketstream will only load the files you specify (rather than every single file that resides in the client/code/app folder - which is the default behaviour).

E.g change this:

```
ss.client.define('main', {
  view: 'app.jade',
  css:  ['libs', 'app.styl'],
  code: ['app'], // This is loading every file within the client/code/app/ folder
  tmpl: '*'
});
```

to this:

```
ss.client.define('main', {
  view: 'app.jade',
  css:  ['libs', 'app.styl'],
  code: ['app/file1.js', 'app/file2.js', 'app/file4.js'], // SS will only load these files.
  tmpl: '*'
});
```